# Inserting Newsletter into CMS page. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, cms, newsletter

I have the code below in a CMS block.  The block is being called in my footer but the template is not. Is there something else I need to do?

```
{{block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" template="Magento_Newsletter::templates/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed "templates" from the path.